# Value Error: Dimension Mismatch .., in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I just followed convolutional neural network tutorial and try to re-write the  code from:
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/convolutional_mlp.py

and I try to change the code from line 108, from:

```
self.output = T.tanh(pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
```

to

```
self.output = T.tanh(conv_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
```

and then I got this error:

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch in args to gemm (500,20000)x(800,500)->(500,500)
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuElemwise{tanh,no_inplace}.0, W)
Toposort index: 40
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(500, 20000), (800, 500)]
Inputs strides: [(20000, 1), (500, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuElemwise{Composite{tanh((i0 + i1))}}[(0, 0)](GpuDot22.0, GpuDimShuffle{x,0}.0)]]
```

I don't know why is this happen, because I think `pooled_out` and `conv_out` have the same shape in the second dimension

can someone help me to explain why is this happen?

Comment: pooled_out is a downsampled version of conv_out by a (2, 2) default window, so I'm of the mind to say that the two do not have matching dimensions anymore.

Comment: but the bias (var b) is added in second dimension (number filters), and pooled_out only have difference dimension with conv_out in third and fourth dimension (height and width image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not inside the `LeNetConvPoolLayer` it's in the following layer which is expecting the output from the `LeNetConvPoolLayer` to be one size but is getting something else.

To skip the pooling, you'll need to adjust every layer that follows a `LeNetConvPoolLayer` to expect its input to be the appropriately larger size.

Comment: oh my god, that's right! thanks, I always thinking that the problem is when adding the bias tensor, I forgot the size can affect the following layer, thanks